# Angular: how to submit form group on enter key pressed

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a form which submits a request to the database to filter some data in a grid. The form is submitted when submit button is pressed but I need it to submit the form when enter key is pressed also.

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="bmForm"
    (keyup.enter)="onSearchClicked()"
    (ngSubmit)="onSearchClicked()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
           <label>Full Text Search</label>
           <input type="name" class="form-control" id="search"
                formControlName="ftSearch"
                placeholder="Full Text Search">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Identifier</label>
            <input type="name" class="form-control" id="search"
                formControlName="id"
                placeholder="Identifier">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button
        type="submit"
        class="btn btn-primary mr-2"
        (keyup.enter)="onSearchClicked()"
        (keydown.enter)="onSearchClicked()">
        Search
    </button>
</form>
```

I have tried using `(keyup.enter)="onSearchClicked()"` in the `<form>` &  `<button>` tag without making changes to the Typescript but have had no success. Currently the Enter tab refreshes the page when clicked.

Comment: do you want to submit form when you press enter key? or tab key?

Comment: @AbdurrahmanY Enter Key

Comment: Your opening form tag is not closed properly, so is your second div and there is no closing tag for your form-group div

Answer (score 3):

Ok. Take a look at my example:
Remove button events, they are unnecessary. Define submit event in your form as `(ngSubmit)` or define it only in button. you don't need more.

```
<form [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="search()">
    <div class="input-group no-border">
        <input type="text" value="" formControlName="key" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
    </div>
</form>
```

and this is the search method:

```
search() {
    this.alert.info('Not yet implemented!');
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this enables the Enter key to submit request?

Comment: Enter key means submit for forms otomatically

Comment: You dont need to specially specify Enter key

Comment: Thanks, but when I do this and press the enter key from the input field it refreshes the page, or sends an empty form search

Comment: I think it is about your Component. Can you show the Component

Comment: Ok, I have found the issue, I  have a clear form button which is placed before the search button so when I press enter it executes the form.reset() from the clear form button

Comment: @rkras, all buttons except "submit" button, must be `type =" button"` otherwise Angular will make it "submit" by default

Answer (score -1):

> The keyup event is sent to an element when the user releases a key on the keyboard. It can be attached to any element, but the event is only sent to the element that has the focus.

Your submit button probably doesn't have focus when the page loads. The function never gets called.

You could force focus to the button by adding the `autofocus` attribute, however this is probably not what you want from a usability perspective (you'd probably want the first text input to have focus).

Try moving `keyup.enter` to the `<form>` element.

```
<form (keyup.enter)="onSearchClicked()">
  // your form
</form>
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work. Inputs might need to handle enter key in a special way. For example autocomplete will need to use the enter key. So first enter will autocomplete and second will submit. Your code cannot handle this scenario.